# Converting a while loop to Reactive Java

Tags: java, reactive-programming, repeat, reactive

I am using Project Reactor in Java. How would I write this blocking while loop in a reactive way?

```
  Flux<Instant> findHistory() {
    int max = 10;
    Instant lastSeenTime = Instant.now();

    List<Instant> instants = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicInteger pageNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);

    while (instants.size() < max) {
      List<Instant> block =
          getHistory(pageNumber.getAndIncrement())
              .filter(instant -> instant.isBefore(lastSeenTime))
              .collectList()
              .block();

      instants.addAll(block);
    }
    return Flux.fromIterable(instants);
  }

  Flux<Instant> getHistory(int pageNumber) {
    // returns the page of Instants
  }
```

I want to keep calling `getHistory` add the result after filtering to my list `instants` until that list has the size of `max`. I have tried to use `repeatWhen` and `expand` but haven't figure out how to use them to achieve what this while loop does.

Comment: I can't test this myself, so I won't write it as a full answer, but as a hint, I think you want to use [`.take(max)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#take-long-)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using take as follows

```
   Flux<Instant> findHistory() {
        int max = 10;
        Instant lastSeenTime = Instant.now();

        return Flux.range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .flatMap(pg -> getHistory(pg))
                .filter(instant -> instant.isBefore(lastSeenTime))
                .take(max);
    }

    Flux<Instant> getHistory(int pageNumber) {
        // returns the page of Instants
    }
```